# What to do with a corrupted DWG file?

Tags: autocad, dwg, libredwg

I work in AutoCAD 2002. The main file of the drawing when opening AutoCAD gives out "It wasn't succeeded to open this drawing. It contains the incorrect or damaged data". Tried to apply the command to "restore" did not help. Writes that found 3 errors and that all recovered. And opens an empty document as if ctrl+n pressed.  Found .the .bak file. when opening it too writes it "It isn't possible to find the specified file of drawing. Be convinced that the specified file exists".  and in the folder with the document there is a text acad file (the log of mistakes)
there it is written: FATAL  ERROR: Unhandled Access Violation Reading 0x0a2a Exception at 4ad3f5h

02/14/2007 at 09:14:15.204 Drawing: way to the file

that for a problem and what to do??? can eat any else options?. it is very necessary drawing!

Comment: DWG files are databases, corruption will not be easy to fix. If AutoCAD's own `RECOVER` command fails, chances are the original data cannot be salvaged. Let's hope you have a recent backup handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to take this file and to open it in AutoCAD 2005. And try to restore the file with the standard tools of AutoCAD 2005. File -> Utilities -> Recover. After this click SAVE in the 2000 format. And then open it in the working AutoCAD 2002 version. Should help.
Go to this resource and see the theme about DWG files.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f956321-2796-49b2-9bd7-6582ad14dd18/drawing-corruptcannot-opencannot-save?forum=itprovistaapps